# code to find IMEI number

Tags: blackberry

What BlackBerry Java code can be used to find a device's IMEI number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The net.rim.device.api.system.GPRSInfo class has a static getIMEI() method. See:

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/GPRSInfo.html

Answer (score 0):

Try This One:

```
import net.rim.device.api.system.*;
public String imei_num = new String(GPRSInfo.imeiToString(GPRSInfo.getIMEI()));
```

Where `imei_num` holds the IMEI Number.